# Mousewheel/touchpad scrolling in Browsers

Tags: mouse, desktop, touchpad, scrolling

I'm not exactly sure how to formulate this, however:

When I scroll using mousewheel or two-finger touchpad gesture, the page in Chrome or Firefox continues scrolling for a bit after I've put my fingers aside from touchpad or mouse.

I don't want this feature in my system, and I'm not sure how is it called. This feature sometimes leads to unwanted behaviour, e.g. if I use ctrl-hotkey in a short sequence after scrolling, page zooms, even though I don't scroll at the time.

2 questions - how this thing is called, and how do I disable it entirely without disabling wheel/touchpad scrolling?

Comment: I found a person with same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/640444/stop-scrolling-on-fingers-up but this thread only encourages to "disable scrolling", which is not something I would want to do.

Comment: I've found the solution for the problem (answered on ubuntu questions); not sure if I should duplicate the answer here. If possible, this question should be removed or set as duplicate of linked question.

Comment: Please post the answer here. There's no mechanism for closing a question as a duplicate of a question on another site because different communities tend to give different answers (for example, we tend to use the command line and configuration files, whereas [ubuntu.se] favors GUIs).

Comment: @Gilles, ok I've duplicated myanswer from linked asubuntu thread.

Comment: If you use X, [this](https://github.com/jarnos/block-scroll-mod-x11) repository may help you in avoiding accidental zooming without totally disabling mousewheel/touchpad scrolling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feature is called "Coasting speed". To disable it you can use:

`xinput --set-prop --type=float "<your device>" "Synaptics Coasting Speed" 0 0`

to list devices you can use:

`xinput list`

alternative variant (for touchpads) is `synclient` options (there are 3 of them):

```
CornerCoasting          = 0
CoastingSpeed           = 0
CoastingFriction        = 0
```

Comment: My device (Logitech K400) does not have that property.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative variant #2, as `xinput` changes are temporary within a session:

In order to make changes permanent, do this:

1. Run `xinput` and find your mouse/touchpad name there.
2. Put a file with this content into /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ directory:

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "Disable Synaptics Coasting"
     MatchDriver "synaptics"
     MatchProduct "<(part of) your device's name>"
     Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"
   EndSection
   ```

For a full and detailed list of options for `synaptics` driver, check this page:

https://www.mankier.com/4/synaptics